# Control fold position while using representer in PyYAML

Tags: python, format, yaml, pyyaml

I am able to dump YAML code with long strings in folded form with this code:

```py
import yaml

class folded_str(str): pass

def folded_str_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='>')

yaml.add_representer(folded_str, folded_str_representer)

data = {
    'foo': folded_str(('abcdefghi ' * 10) + 'end\n'),
}

print(yaml.dump(data))
```

The output for the above code is:

```
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi end
```

Is it possible to control the length after which the folds should occur? For example, if I want the lines to fold after 70 characters, then the output would look like this:

```
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi end
```

Is there a way to make PyYAML do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to control how long the lines that PyYAML puts out with
folding, is to provide the (global) line length with the parameter `width`:

```
import sys
import yaml

class folded_str(str): pass

def folded_str_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='>')

yaml.add_representer(folded_str, folded_str_representer)

data = {
    'foo': folded_str(('abcdefghi ' * 10) + 'end\n'),
}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, width=70)
```

which gives:

```
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi end
```

As you can see, I removed your call to `print`. PyYAML has a streaming
interface and by not directly streaming to output, it needs to make an
in-memory interpretation of the output which is both unnecessarily slow and memory
in-efficient.

Of course this also affects any other lines that get dumped (long
non-folded scalars, flow-style lists, deeply nested data-structures.

The non-easy way is not to call the `represent_scalar` routine, and
adapt PyYAML's `ScalarNode` (or create your own `Node` type), that
then does output a newline in the appropriate position when emitting.

---

My `ruamel.yaml` has this functionality built in, to allow such output to round-trip
with the fold position preserved (even thought the default output width is the same
as PyYAML's)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
[long, scalar]: "This is just a filler to show that the default width is 80 chars"
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi end
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
[long, scalar]: This is just a filler to show that the default width is 80 chars
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi end
```

Although you can create such a folded string from scratch, it is not trivial (there is 
no API, and the internal representation might change). What I recommend is
just creating the folded string data and then loading it by defining your `folded_str` differntly:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

def folded_str(s, pos=70):
    parts = []
    r = ""
    for part in s.split(' '):
        if not r:
            r = part
        elif len(r) + len(part) >= pos:
            parts.append(r + '\n')
            r = part
        else:
            r += ' ' + part
    parts.append(r)
    return yaml.load(">\n" + "".join(parts))

data = {
    'foo': folded_str(('abcdefghi ' * 10) + 'end\n'),
}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
foo: >
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi
  abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi end
```

Comment: For those of you wondering where the (superfluous) quotes around `This is just a filler....` went, you can preserve these on round-trip by setting `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`